# How to use GETPIVOTDATA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

[image: Sample Image]

I'm trying to populate the field C4, which is the "# of Sessions" Grand Total (in this sample, M16) *10 / the "[redacted] Contribution Fee" Grand Total (in this sample, M15). But, I need it to work even if are more rows/columns added, etc. (e.g. I'm going to get numbers from November soon, so the Grand Total column will move to N).

In order to achieve this, I'm accustomed to using INDEX-MATCH or the like, but it looks like that doesn't work on Pivot Tables. So I've tried using GETPIVOTDATA instead. The problem is that I can't get the field to populate. I'm using,

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("SUM of How many sessions did you have this month?", A10)
```

I keep getting the ERROR "Field combination not found in pivot table for function GETPIVOTDATA."

I thought it was that I renamed "SUM of How many sessions did you have this month?" to "# of Sessions," but that doesn't seem to work either. Can someone help me understand what my problem is?

Comment: do you want `=M16*10/M15` or `=M15*10/M16` ??

Comment: The former. =M16*10/M15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `=M16*10/M15` try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Contribution Fee", B:B,   0), 
                  MATCH("Grand Total",      11:11, 0)))*10/
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("# of Sessions",    B:B,   0), 
                  MATCH("Grand Total",      11:11, 0)))
```

for `=M15*10/M16` try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("# of Sessions",    B:B,   0), 
                  MATCH("Grand Total",      11:11, 0)))*10/
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Contribution Fee", B:B,   0), 
                  MATCH("Grand Total",      11:11, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's what I got: "Error
Did not find value 'Counsellors Contribution Fee' in MATCH evaluation." I tried it with both the "Renamed" Row Name and the "Original" Row Name.

Comment: @AdamGosnell can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much @player0. I'm going to remove this link now.